# How do you make maps in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm having trouble crafting, or otherwise obtaining, a map item in Minecraft PE. Could anyone explain how I would go about obtaining a map?

Comment: What have you tried? What's going wrong? Also, do you mean a minecraft map, or the in game "map" item?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make maps on Minecraft Pocket Edition, they have simply not been implemented yet.

You can see a full list of items and blocks available on pocket edition here:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it in-game, but [MCEdit does support MC PE maps.](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-discussion/1962452-windows-mac-linux-edit-your-mc-pe-worlds-with)